# How to return my current time zone in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time, timezone

When I use return the time that the record created, it show this :

> 2010-01-20 15:04:40 UTC

but I want the time in my specify time zone, for example, China. Is there any convenient method in RoR?

Comment: I am using ruby 1.8.7 , Rails 2.3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configure your time zone in  `config/environment.rb` to have Rails cast all timestamps to this time zone.

```
config.time_zone = 'Berlin'
```

As an alternative you can always use something like

```
Time.utc(2000).in_time_zone('Alaska')
```

See the documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Time/Zones/in_time_zone).

Comment: does it supports ruby 1.8.7 , Rails 2.3.2 ? because it seems not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the TimeZone and TimeWithZone classes. They add time zone support. There's also been some additions to the Time and DateTime classes that also help deal with time zones. The documentation is given here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html.

There's also an excellent post here giving some extra details: http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/1/25/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-easier-timezones